# How to create alias for first active item in reverse relation in Django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model called Item:

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    ...
```

Also I have another model called Content. It has relation to Item and a ChoiceField to select is the content is active or not:

```py
class Content(models.Model):
    item = ForeignKey(Item related_name=)
    is_active = BooleanField(default=False)
    content = TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       """There's a logic to make sure every item has only one content"""
```

I have two questions.

1. How to filter out the Items without any content or without any active content.
2. Can I do something like alias to call item.content to return active content of the item without causing db performance issues.

Comment: Just for context: do you want to make a query of only the items that have no active content?

Comment: I want to make a query of only items that HAS active content.

Comment: You have the option to filter using your content model like `Content.objects.filter(is_active=True).values_list('item__pk', flat=True)` this should return a list of item primary keys... is that what you mean? Then you can use that list to query your items model.

Comment: Is there only one such `Content` *per* `Item`?

Answer (score 0):

> How to filter out the Items without any content or without any active content.

You filter with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Content.objects.filter(~Q(content=''), is_active=True)
```

> Can I do something like alias to call item.content to return active content of the item without causing db performance issues.

Given the related name looks like:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    item = ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='contents')
```

You can prefetch these `Content`s to the `contents` with:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch, Q

Item.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('contents', Content.objects.filter(~Q(content=''), is_active=True))
)
```

For these `Item`s, it will set the `.contents.all()` to the related `Content`s with `content` not being empty, and `is_active` being `True`.